Should I use an op-amp buffer so I'm not affecting the original source's current requirements?
I'm attempting to modify an existing product (a dance stage similar to Dance Dance Revolution) where the panel signal is held high (5V) and when it is pressed it pulls the signal low (0V.) Only High (5V) and Low (0V) are important as this is a digital signal. There are nine independent signals that I want to tap into and potentially output to various microcontrollers (Pico, Arduino, etc.) to read this signal and do something with it. My worry is that I don't want to affect the original signal at all (or affect it as little as possible,) and I'm worried that multiplying it out to various other Arduinos will affect it negatively such that the original intent for the signal is degraded.
I don't know too much about buffers, but my understanding was that I could use something like the schematic below (whether inverted or not, I haven't really decided yet,) and then use the outputs rather than the inputs so I could potentially pull more current if necessary without affecting the original signals.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If it helps, I have access to 12V and 5V power sources, and thinking about it more I think it would actually be better if the buffers output something closer to 3V3 as a lot of microcontrollers don't necessarily work on 5V logic.
Does this seem like a reasonable idea? Is there a better solution? Any suggestions on what opamps to use?

Are the signals binary?  I.e., are they always either 5V or 0V, with nothing useful in between?  Or are they analog, where the signal ranges from 0V to 5V, but all intermediate values have meaning?

Yes, it's either on (5V) or off (0V).

My apologies, I didn't notice you're a newbie.  Stackexchange wants all the relevant information in the question itself, not buried in the comments.  Please edit your question with this tidbit -- it's important.

You should leave the original circuit in place. Add the second circuit as an update. Otherwise Spehro's answer doesn't make sense. Please don't change the question in such a way to make existing correct answers incorrect.

ah I see. Thank you for the corrections. I have reverted the schematic, and put the answer to the first comment in the post itself.

The circuit you show will attempt to short the input to ground to the extent the op-amp and associated supplies will allow it so it's less than ideal from the viewpoint of leaving the inputs unmolested.
If your signal are logic level (like 0/+5V with respect to GND) you can just use simple buffers or inverters, such as 74HC7014 (non-inverting) or 74HC14 (inverting). Those ones have Schmitt trigger inputs so they are more tolerant of input noise etc. You should put the buffers near the source to keep from affecting the input signals.
If you have to transmit the signals a long distance it might be better take the buffered input and drive the output with something differential such as RS485 levels or LVDS (which doubles the number of signal lines but has other advantages). That's not the subject of your question but you should consider it. If the signals only change in human-scale time then you could probably do fine with a remote 74HC14->long wire->RC filter->74HC14 (local to the Arduino).

Oops, I think I had the circuit wrong in the first place. That being said, I think your solution makes sense. The distances aren't going to be crazy long so I probably don't need to go differential. I'm going to look into those chips, thanks!

Use a digital buffer, like a 74HC244.  Op-amps are for analog signals -- they work great for that, but from a price & complexity standpoint a digital buffer will work better.
Or, since the signals are slow, try using no buffers at all.  That may work just fine.
